# i have the problem in i18next that the text not show from json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

i tried more then one way to do it but it didn't work idk whey !!
the text showing like i write it don't become from the json file .
i make it more then one time to be sure i don't have any mistakes .
so please if you know what is the problem can you tell me .
[image: i18next file]

[image: packag.Json file]

[image: import i18n file]
[[image: text i want to show how it show]
[image: data json file and files paths]
[image: the json file and path]
[image: the result it doesn't show]

note : i tried i18n in a file and in the index.js file and both doesn't work
i hope you find the mistake . thanks for everyone try to help

The error types is :

```
i18next.js:27 i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace common for language en failed failed parsing ../public/assets/i18n/common/en.json to json

i18next.js:27 i18next::backendConnector: loading namespace about for language en failed failed parsing ../public/assets/i18n/about/en.json to json
i18next::translator: missingKey en home home home
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `resources` attributes

```
import { en } from './en.json'

.
.
.

    resources: {
      en:en,
    },
```

and

```
backendOptions: [
        {
          loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        },
      ],
```

Comment: hello , i tried to put it but there is nothing named resources and when i import the en.json it show an error for importing and {en} not defined in the i18n file so i dont know whats wrong with that i add the backendoptiton and it work with out error but the result still the same

Comment: maybe `import en from './en.json'` instead.  I'm not sure of the import syntax, but you just need to point out that the resources you are using is from that .json file

Comment: I really suspect the json file is not valid json format... check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805320/1859027

Comment: btw: for a general usage of react-i18next with inline resources and lazy loaded resources can be found in this guide: https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your json files are not valid json format.
It may be there is some additional comma (,) at the end or similar…
Validate your json files.

For example put the json content here and check for errors: https://jsonlint.com/